# SAX xml parser or DOM parser?

Tags: java

Is this using a SAX or DOM parser?

```
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document     document = docBuilder.parse(file);
```

Comment: Is this `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory` ?Then it is DOM

Answer (score 2):

A DOM Parser

**DocumentBuilderFactory**

Defines a factory API that enables applications to obtain a parser that produces DOM object trees from XML documents.